# Android, Cmdline tool, NDK => SIGBUS

Tags: android, linux, assembly, android-ndk, arm

### Environment

- Android 5
- Samsung Galaxy S5 ( ARM )
- C++ ADB Commandline tool

For the following code I get SIGBUS while executing "**fCapacity /= (float)100.0f;**"

```
                HRESULT getBatteryCapacity(OUT OUT float& fCapacity) {
                FILE* fp = fopen("/sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity", "rt");
                if (0 == fp)
                    return HRESULT_FROM_ERRNO(errno);
                char pText[16] = { 0 };
                char* pRet = fgets(pText, sizeof(pText), fp);
                int iLastErr = errno;
                fclose(fp);
                if (0 == pRet)
                    return HRESULT_FROM_ERRNO(iLastErr);
                pRet = 0;
                fCapacity = strtof(pText, &pRet);
                if (pRet == pText)
                    return HRESULT_FROM_ERRNO(iLastErr);
                fCapacity /= (float)100.0f; // Causing SIGBUS
                return S_OK;
            }
```

Digging through assembly I can see that the code break while executing "**vldr s15, [r3]**" ( loading a memory address to a 32 bit floating point register )

```
    ...
        return HRESULT_FROM_ERRNO(iLastErr);
    0xb6ef7ba0  ldr r3, [r11, # - 36]; 0x24
    0xb6ef7ba4  orr r3, r3, # - 2147483648; 0x80000000
    0xb6ef7ba8  orr r3, r3, #49152; 0xc000
    0xb6ef7bac  b 0xb6ef7bcc <Mobile::Android::Device::Utility::getBatteryCapacity(float&) + 344>
        fCapacity /= (float)100.0f;
    0xb6ef7bb0  ldr r3, [r11, # - 48]; 0x30
    0xb6ef7bb4  vldr s15, [r3] // <== Breaks here
    0xb6ef7bb8  vldr s14, [pc, #52]; 0xb6ef7bf4 <Mobile::Android::Device::Utility::getBatteryCapacity(float&) + 384>
    0xb6ef7bbc  vdiv.f32 s15, s15, s14
    0xb6ef7bc0  ldr r3, [r11, # - 48]; 0x30
    0xb6ef7bc4  vstr s15, [r3]
        return S_OK;
    0xb6ef7bc8  mov r3, #0
}
```

Must there be any memory addr alignment for data loaded into the 32 bit floating point registers ?

**UPDATE:**
The following ( memcpy ) solved the problem, **but Why????**

```
float fCap = strtof(pText, &pRet);
if (pRet == pText)
    return HRESULT_FROM_ERRNO(iLastErr);
fCap /= (float)100.0f;
memcpy(&fCapacity, &fCap, sizeof(fCap));
```

Comment: I don't think any of this code is the problem - how are you invoking the function (i.e. where and how is the variable passed as `fCapacity` defined)? The compiler should guarantee appropriate alignment for all data types, so it suggests something fishy is happening elsewhere. The fact that the "proper" way to write a value to an unaligned location (via `memcpy`) prevents an alignment fault is not, in itself, all that interesting ;)

Comment: 'fCapacity' is on the heap, part of a struct allocated using new, what should be the alignment? I would expect the compiler to avoid such errors...

Comment: Floating-point values must be word-aligned - if the address of `fCapacity` isn't a multiple of 4 then you'll have to track down why (structure packing and pointer casts are the likely culprits).